# Arabic Numbers (indian Number)

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application I need to application to write the indain numbers in the input and display I change the Format setting from control panel and set it to saudi Arabia and in the additional settings use native digits to national and standard digits to indain

and still have problem on Internet explorer 10 but work on 7 and 8 ? any ideas

note : this is an example of indian number

http://postimg.org/image/513t1zv1f/

Comment: a) "still have problem": could you explain *what* problem? b) "control panel": on which computer: browser or server? c) Did you use any culture settings in your application?

Answer (score 1):

According to wiki there are two variants of these numbers:- "Western Arabic" and "Eastern Arabic.

You probably need the Eastern Arabic so you can try like this:-

```
const UInt16 sh = 0x0660 - 0x0030;

//...

string myString(int value) {
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    String lst = value.ToString();
    foreach(char x in lst) {
        UInt16 c = Convert.ToUInt16(x);
        c+= sh;
        s.Append(Convert.ToChar(c));
    }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is that `lst` variable?

Comment: @HansKesting:- It is just a collection. Actually initially I thought that it is possible through this way also:- int myInteger = //
string s= //?
string a= myInteger.ToString(new System.CultureInfo(s));
 
//using a different constructor:
int i= //?
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(i);

Comment: It's just that the code you posted never uses the `value` and does use an undefined `lst`. Probably there should be a `string lst = value.ToString();` added.

Comment: ok thats fine but i need when i write in a Rich text editor show numbers directlly